# "no such column adoptions_pet.submissions.date" error

Tags: python, django

Doing the "Become a Django dev" on LI Learning. However, I have trouble getting the column date values of a .csv into my website.

The error goes, after visiting http://localhost:8000/admin/adoptions/pet/:
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: adoptions_pet.submissions_date

The db.sqlite3 file looks fine in my DB browser.
[db browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73zXB.png)

models.py file:

```
 from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, blank=True)
    submissions_date = models.DateTimeField()
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations = models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine', blank=True)

class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

load.pet.data.py

```
from csv import DictReader
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.management import BaseCommand

from adoptions.models import Pet, Vaccine
from pytz import UTC


DATETIME_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

VACCINES_NAMES = [
    'Canine Parvo',
    'Canine Distemper',
    'Canine Rabies',
    'Canine Leptospira',
    'Feline Herpes Virus 1',
    'Feline Rabies',
    'Feline Leukemia'
]

ALREDY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE = """
If you need to reload the pet data from the CSV file,
first delete the db.sqlite3 file to destroy the database.
Then, run `python manage.py migrate` for a new empty
database with tables"""


class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "Loads data from pet_data.csv into our Pet mode"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if Vaccine.objects.exists() or Pet.objects.exists():
            print('Pet data already loaded...exiting.')
            print(ALREDY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            return
        print("Creating vaccine data")
        for vaccine_name in VACCINES_NAMES:
            vac = Vaccine(name=vaccine_name)
            vac.save()
        print("Loading pet data for pets available for adoption")
        for row in DictReader(open('./pet_data.csv')):
            pet = Pet()
            pet.name = row['Pet']
            pet.submitter = row['Submitter']
            pet.species = row['Species']
            pet.breed = row['Breed']
            pet.description = row['Pet Description']
            pet.sex = row['Sex']
            pet.age = row['Age']
            raw_submission_date = row['submission date']
            submission_date = UTC.localize(
                datetime.strptime(raw_submission_date, DATETIME_FORMAT))
            pet.submission_date = submission_date
            pet.save()
            raw_vaccination_names = row['vaccinations']
            vaccination_names = [name for name in raw_vaccination_names.split('| ') if name]
            for vac_name in vaccination_names:
                vac = Vaccine.objects.get(name=vac_name)
                pet.vaccinations.add(vac)
            pet.save()
```

I have the feeling something is going wrong here, but I'm not sure:

```
raw_submission_date = row['submission date']
            submission_date = UTC.localize(
                datetime.strptime(raw_submission_date, DATETIME_FORMAT))
            pet.submission_date = submission_date
```

The traceback I get on http://localhost:8000/admin/adoptions/pet/

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/adoptions/pet/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'adoptions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such column: adoptions_pet.submissions_date) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1796, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/adoptions/pet/
Exception Value: no such column: adoptions_pet.submissions_date
```

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: Yes, I did run migrations through the >python manage.py makemigration. Created db.sqlite3 file that was showing properly in DB browser. Hope this is what you mean. I edited my original post to include the traceback found on localhost:8000/admin/adoptions/pets

Comment: I found that in models.py I entered: submissions_date = models.DateTimeField() instead of submission_date = models.DateTimeField()
So submission without the "s"

This solved the problem.